# For what is this second that-clause placed?

Tags: relative-clauses

> “. . . I’ll bet he killed a man.” She narrowed her eyes and shivered.
>   Lucille shivered. We all turned and looked for Gatsby. It was
>   testimony to the romantic speculation he inspired **that** there were
>   whispers about him from those who had found little **that** it was
>   necessary to whisper about in this world. 
> (F. Scott Fitzgerald, The
>   Great Gatsby)

The first ‘that’ seems to take a role adding information about ‘speculation.’ But I’m wondering for what the second that-clause is placed. Would you let me know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second *that* introduces a relative clause which modifies *little*. In effect:

> It was necessary to whisper about little in this world.

*This world* is the society is the ‘smart set’, the wealthy would-be sophisticates among whom the novel is set. In saying that they “found little that it was necessary to whisper about”, the narrator implies that they made a point of speaking quite frankly about matters which an older generation spoke about only in whispers.  That they **did** speak about Gatsby in whispers is for that reason remarkable—the “romantic speculation he inspired” involves matters which are unusually scandalous.

Comment: Thank you very much. Having humble eye, I couldn’t have seen the relative clause, even after having a reply saying the same in a Korean forum. [link](http://k.daum.net/qna/view.html?qid=55HBF). There’s a halo effect even in the replies, for I don’t have the confidence before getting your reply.

Answer (score 1):

You could rephrase it as

> ...from those who had found little **reason** that it was necessary to whisper about in this world.

It basically means

> ...from those who had found that it was **unnecessary** to whisper about in this world.

So, it was mostly unnecessary to whisper about the romantic speculation he inspired.

Comment: Your rephrasings make no sense to me.  As written, I don't believe that either of them is even grammatical.